# Вариация паттерна MVC

Tags: mvc, шаблоны-проектирования

Здравствуйте, опять вопрос простого уровня. Есть известный всем паттерн MVC. Читал, что существует много его вариаций, для использования в общей структуре десктопных приложений. Для себя решил, что будет удобна такая вариация:
Ядро (Core)
Интерфейс (Interface)
Графический интерфейс (GUI)

То есть в объекте ядра создаются объекты, которые представляют собой некие хранилища функций. Гуя она и есть гуя, только в моем варианте, внутри нее, задается только расположения кнопочек и всего остального, плюс внешний вид. Плюс создается словар, в который помещаются все ссылки на объекты гуи. В объекте Интерфейса, происходит связывания элементов Гуи и функций из внутренних объектов ядра.

Что скажете, глупость, или имеет право на жизнь на практике?

Comment: В каком языке или фреймворке собираетесь использовать?

Comment: python, pyside.
Работаю в IDLE.

Мне честно сказать это вообще интересует, если можете какие-то интересные мысли изложить на данную тему, я с удовольствием прочитаю, мне интересно вообще разные архитектурные решения, ваш опыт, какие траблы возникали.

Comment: Основная мысль: писать собственные реализации паттерном проектирования - не самая лучшая затея, используйте готовый фреймворки!

Comment: Использовать готовые фреймворки тоже не самая лучшая идея.

Собственные начинания всегда похвальны. Вы бы по существу что-то бы ответили.

ЗЫ: по теме лишь скажу - старайтесь что бы "ядро" и "интерфейс" вообще не зависил от гуя. В этом основная идея. Интерфейс должен предоставлять возможности ядра, а гуй использовал интерфейс.

Comment: Так у меня получает так, что объект "ядра" создается и просто содержит набор функций, но сам по факту ничего не делает, а является своего рода хранилищем и исполнителем особо сложно связанных функций, но выполнение, которых запускает гуя. Гуй то же создается, как объект пустышка, внутри которого ничего не работает, просто создаются кнопки, таблички и так далее. А, вот, объект интерфейс связывает и выполняет основную работу по конструированию программы, то есть, к каждой кнопке гуя привязывает то, что она должна делать из внутренностей ядра.

Comment: >Использовать готовые фреймворки тоже не самая лучшая идея

почему-то ``.Net`` и ``jQuery`` прекрасно используются и на них есть спрос, хотя это фреймворки, тоже самое можно сказать про ``Zend``, ``Django``, ``Rails``...список можно продолжать

мне вот больше интеречно, чем тов. @ShestakoffVS не угодил MVC?

Comment: Что-то сильно напоминает Model-View от Qt

Comment: Spectre 

Ну, просто стандартная MVC, получается, что ГУЯ делиться на две части, одна отвечает за отображение (View) и за взаимодействие (Controller) и все остальное, в том числе и вязи все сидят в модели. Как-то это нелогично на уровне расположения кода. К примеру внутри ГУИ у меня лежать и те элементы, что отвечают за отображение и те, что за управление, и все это смешано и получается какая-то свалка. А так, у меня все разделено на три модуля, и физически, и логически. Так, вот, я собственно и спрашивал, может, я соли не прочувствовал в модели МВЦ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> внутри ГУИ у меня лежать и те элементы, что отвечают за отображение и те, что за управление

это уже не `View`, а `Widget`

> получается, что ГУЯ делиться на две части, одна отвечает за отображение (View) и за взаимодействие (Controller) и все остальное, в том числе и вязи все сидят в модели

как-то неправильно получается: `View` - это всего лиш внешний вид; то, что увидит пользователь; чаще всего соответсвует отоброжению некоторой модели(`Model`), но т.к. модель предметной области иногда может не соответсвовать модели отображения, вводят ещё и `ViewModel`, которая может соответствовать даже нескольким моделям, уже с ней и работает `View`. А уже все действия пользователя обрабатывает `Controller`. Именно он изменяет модель и выдаёт пользователю различное представление.

Какой-то программист однажды сказал:

`"Представления должны быть тупыми, контрллеры - тощими, а модели - толстыми"`

Благодаря такой архитектуре, приложение легко тестируется и ещё легче расширяется.

**НО** не стоит заморачиватся над этим, не ограничивайте себя такими решениями, если вы считаете, что в вашем конкретном случае приложение должно иметь другую, пусть даже более примитивную, архитектуру, делайте! Приложение должно выполнять поставленую задачу, должно быть удобно в использовании, должно быть устойчивым к ошибкам, а следовать какой-то архитектуре - это одна из последних задач. Конечно, если вы затели делать новый Facebook . . . всё иначе=)

Comment: Начало понял с трудом, но примерно понял. За фразу "одного программиста" отдельное спасибо, это уже важный момент. И Facebook свой не буду делать, и программка маленькая, но ваши советы учту и приму на вооружение, и еще раз спасибо)

Comment: @ShestakoffVS , квинтэссенция ответа заключается в **НО не стоит заморачиватся над этим, не ограничивайте себя такими решениями**.

Comment: avp, ага это я то же учел)))

Answer (score 0):

[MVVM](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-View-ViewModel) из этой же оперы